# Httpwebrequest--POST method using text file

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, couchdb

I am trying to replicate a Couch database using .NET classes instead of a curl command line. I have never used WebRequest or Httpwebrequest before, but I am attempting to use them to make a post request with the script below.

Here is the JSON script for couchdb replication(I know this works):

```
{ ""_id"":"database_replicate8/7/12", "source":sourcedb, ""target"":"targetDB", ""create_target"":true, ""user_ctx"": { ""roles"": ["myrole"] } }
```

The above script is put into a text file, sourcefile.txt. I want to take this line and put it in a POST web request using .NET functionality.

After looking into it, I chose to use the httpwebrequest class. Below is what I have so far--I got this from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx

```
 HttpWebRequest bob = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("sourceDBURL");
 bob.Method = "POST";
 bob.ContentType = "application/json";
 byte[] bytearray = File.ReadAllBytes(@"sourcefile.txt");
 Stream datastream = bob.GetRequestStream();
 datastream.Write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
 datastream.Close();
```

Am I going about this correctly? I am relatively new to web technologies and still learning how http calls work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method I use for creating POST requests:

```
 private static HttpWebRequest createNewPostRequest(string apikey, string secretkey, string endpoint)
 {
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(endpoint) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Proxy = null;
    request.Method = "POST";
    //Specify the xml/Json content types that are acceptable. 
    request.ContentType = "application/xml";
    request.Accept = "application/xml";

    //Attach authorization information
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", apikey);
    request.Headers.Add("Secretkey", secretkey);
    return request;
 }
```

Within my main method I call it like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = createNewPostRequest(apikey, secretkey, endpoint);
```

and I then pass my data to the method like this:

```
string requestBody = SerializeToString(requestObj);

byte[] byteStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody);
request.ContentLength = byteStr.Length;

using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(byteStr, 0, byteStr.Length);
}

//Parse the response
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    //Business error
    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Error: response status code is{0}, at time:{1}", response.StatusCode, DateTime.Now.ToString()));

        return "error";
    }
    else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)//Success
    {
        using (Stream respStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SubmitReportResponse));
            reportReq = serializer.Deserialize(respStream) as SubmitReportResponse;
        }

     }
...
```

In my case I serialize/deserialize my body from a class - you will need to alter this to use your text file. If you want an easy drop in solution, then change the `SerializetoString` method to a method that loads your text file to a string.